# IntelliJ Idea Ctrl+Alt+Left shortcut doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Idea 2017.3 latest release in Ubuntu 2017.10 and shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> doesn't work.

Whereas from menu Navigate -> Back/Forward works fine.

Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigation-in-source-code.html

Comment: Does it work in other apps?

Comment: I use Eclipse too and the shortcut is Alt+Left/Right which works fine. I am not sure about other apps having the same shortcut, kindly let me know in case you are aware of any. Also Ubuntu doesn't have any default shortcuts with Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right

Comment: Try remapping it in keymap and see if this key is recognized. If not, it's probably already used by some other app.

Comment: Keymap is set to Default for XWin and there are not such shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right to remap. Tried changing it to Default for GNOME and still the same.

Comment: I mean try to assign this shortcut to some action to see if IDE recognizes it.

Comment: IDE isn't recognising the keystroke Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right when i tried changing it for some other action.

Comment: It means it's already taken by some other app or system.

Comment: My bad, Ubuntu has a shortcut Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right to navigate between workspaces. When i changed it under system settings, IDE is able to pick up the shortcut. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Post your comment as the answer, @Samy! And mark it as the accepted answer. ... Profit.

Comment: my keyboard is not working when i copy the text

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu has a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> to navigate between workspaces. When i changed it under system settings, IDE is able to pick up the shortcut.

Comment: Any idea how to change this setting in 2018.04?

Comment: @GarethA.Lloyd check my answer.

Comment: @GarethA.Lloyd You may change it under System Settings->Devices    ->Keyboard under navigation section.

Comment: @Samy in 2018.04 you can't change these particular shortcuts via that menu anymore

Comment: I am using 18.04 and I could change it still.

Comment: @Samy clean install or upgrade from previous version? In my case (a clean install) there are no items for "Switch to workspace left/right", only for "Switch to last workspace" and "Switch to workspace 1/2/3/4".

Comment: It was upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04. Hence I could still see those options?

Comment: yo0u have to do some manipulation as it is written here above. by @kuceraf

Answer (score 316):

Ubuntu binds this key combination to *Switch Workspace*. Starting from Ubuntu 18.04, you need to use the command line to change the shortcut ([source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings)), because the Ubuntu Keyboard Settings GUI might not show this option. Simply removing all shortcuts for that action is the easiest way to allow IntelliJ to use them:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"
```

However, as user @stackunderflow writes, *"there is no need to remove **all** gnome key bindings for `switch-to-workspace-left` and `switch-to-workspace-right`".* If you want to keep the non-conflicting ones, see [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77769515/147806).

In any case, if you ever want to restore the shortcuts, use:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right
```

**Default keymap**

In addition, your IntelliJ installation might be set to the the *default for GNOME* keymap instead of the one you're used to. This maps  the *Navigate - Forward* and *Navigate - Backward* shortcuts to `Ctrl` + `Alt` + *`Windows Key`* + `Left/Right`. Under `File > Settings > Keymap`, you can either modify the key combination for just those shortcuts, or switch to the *default* keymap entirely.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 it worked fine and seems to be the only way to resolve the problem.

Comment: Seems to be Gnome specific, tried it on Kali linux 2018.2, it worked as well

Comment: This shortcut not working was really annoying me for a month. I couldn't find it in settings and my firsts thoughts were that the problem is with ubuntu ran as a vmware guest. Thanks a lot! Why would they hide these shortcuts from settings?

Comment: Must be an oversight in Ubuntu 18.04 since here _Move to Workspace_ has been changed to **Up** and **Down** - removing the dependency on those keybindings. As such they are not listed in _Setings>Devices>Keyboard Shortcuts_ but I still had to remove the bindings as above in order to free them up

Comment: It works on Debian 9 as well. Simpler way using UI: Show all applications(Super+A) -> Settings -> Keyboard -> Click Search -> Search "Move to Workspace" -> Click "Move to workspace left" -> Press Delete to unassign -> Click "Move to workspace right" -> Press Delete to unassign.

Comment: Did not work for me on Mint 19.2.
Needed to use shift+alt+left/right as mentioned on [barbsan's other comment on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53707163/1041319).

Comment: You may want to install `dconf-tools` and run `dconf-editor` to edit these settings via GUI. That's text-mode for the values anyway but still more convenient than console.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Comment: yo0u have to do some manipulation as it is written here above. by @kuceraf

Comment: This solutions works fine in CLion 2020.1, Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: For anyone wondering if this can be done from Ubuntu settings UI, the answer is **not always**. Not all the shortcuts are displayed in settings, therefore this approach must sometimes be used, see also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098479/713476).

Comment: Works on Manjaro 20.2.1 Gnome (Gnome 2.38)

Comment: @topr 's solution worked on 20.04

Comment: Still works on Ubuntu 22.04! Amazing how these hidden shortcuts (from a user perspective) remain hidden.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20,
Adding `Windows key` to the combo works,
So it is not a must to run the offered `gsettings` instuctions

Answer (score 54):

I just found out that my IDEA 2018.3 in Ubuntu 18.04 automatically uses **default for GNOME** keymap, and the Back/Forward shotcut turns out to be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>, no need to change any system settings.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful! Didn't know about this.

Comment: Needed to make sure the IntelliJ keymap setting was "default for gnome" in settings as well.

Comment: this comment should be marked as the answer of the question, thanks!

Comment: This keymap navigates between tabs, not code :( CLion 2020.1, Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 22):

The right setting is combinations of already posted answers. To sum up:

**1. Remove key bindings of Ctrl+Alt+Right/Left to GNOME enviroment**

In terminal run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"
```

**2. Assigne the bindings to Forward / Back actions in Idea IntelliJ**

If you use Keymap setting based on  GNOME keymap the defaults for Forward / Back actions are not Ctrl+Alt+Right/Left. It must be setted.

In Idea IntelliJ menu

```
File | Settings | Keymap
```

search for

```
Main menu - Navigate - Forward
```

click on edit shortcuts and set it to Ctrl+Alt+Right

then search for

```
Main menu - Navigate - Back
```

click on edit shortcuts and set it to Ctrl+Alt+Left

Works on versions:
Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Idea IntelliJ 2019.2.3

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> worked on my Linux Fedora 22.

Comment: What is "for me". Please define your environment.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's Linux Fedora 22. Thanks!

Comment: strange  <kbd>Ctrl+Win+Alt</kbd> is not registered at all in my install, Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 9):

In Ubuntu System settings you have to either desible shortcut for `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Left/Right` or use `Ctrl` + `Windows Key` + `Alt` + `Left/Right`

Comment: Thanks! Ctrl+WindowsKey+Alt+Left/Right works for my Ubuntu18.04 also.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

1. Go to System Settings -> Text Entry -> Keyboard Settings (bottom right of the screen).
2. On the keyboard dialog, click on Navigation tab. Then scroll down to "switch to workspace left" and select it and click backspace to disable it.

Your android studio shortcut should work now.

Answer (score 3):

The solution by @lászló-van-den-hoek here was correct, but I had to take one more step.

Go to `File | Settings | Keymap` in Intellij and change the Keymap from `Default for GNOME` to `Default`.

I think this has been tripping people up since Ubuntu switched from Unity desktop to a GNOME based desktop, and now Intellij is starting up with GNOME appropriate hotkeys.

Answer (score 3):

For Linux Mint Cinnamon, the default workspace switching keybinding that interferes with IntelliJ keybinding can be changed with the following :

Disable:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-to-workspace-left "@as []"
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-to-workspace-right "@as []"
```

Reset to defaults:

```
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-to-workspace-left
gsettings reset org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm switch-to-workspace-right
```

Thanks @László for the Ubuntu Gnome hint.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to remove **all** gnome key bindings for **switch-to-workspace-left** and **switch-to-workspace-right** (as some other answers suggested). Just remove the conflicting bindings.

First check which keys are currently assigned:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right
```

You may see

```
['<Super>Page_Up', '<Super><Alt>Left', '<Control><Alt>Left']
['<Super>Page_Down', '<Super><Alt>Right', '<Control><Alt>Right']
```

And then set the new bindings, but omit the conflict keys, e.g:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['<Super>Page_Up', '<Super><Alt>Left']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['<Super>Page_Down', '<Super><Alt>Right']"
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind using Alt-Shift instead of Alt-Ctrl, go with frank's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Windows + Left/Right ; Ubuntu 20.04, IDEA: 2020.1, works for me

Answer (score 0):

My Gnome was configured to CTRL+ALT+left or right and I don't why but it moved to CTRL+ALT+Up or down. Workspaces were aligned horizontally and they changed to be vertical. I don't what I did to get this! Maybe the same thing happened to you...

I am fine with that, it changes a lit bit my desktop, changes are good some times...

I advice you to install the extension Workspace to dock which is very cool  ;)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

1. Click the keyboard on the right of UI ==> `Input Method Configuration` will appear.
   [image]
2. Click `Global Config` and then `Show Advanced Options`.
3. Remove Hotkey `Saving All Confg and Input History`.

Answer (score 0):

In LUbuntu 20.04 the offendig settings were found in `.config/openbox/lxqt-rc.xml`. They are expected to be editable by `lxqt-config-globalkeyshortcuts` app (Preferences -> LXQt settings -> Shortcut keys), but are not shown in the app.

Ref: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.14/shortcut_keys.html

`gsettings` and `dconf` appear unrelated

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the original issue, but I'm leaving it as an answer here since this question pops up in google search results - in my case Android Studio 2020.3.1 on ArchLinux Gnome (with Gnome keymap in AS settings) Alt+Shift+Left/Right do not work because the are already assigned (what?!) on other actions.

Going to `File / Settings / Keymap / Main Menu / Navigate / Back` then `Add Keyboard shortcut` shows a warning `Already assigned to: Select Previous Tab in multi-editor file and Accept Rigth Side in VCS` - right, already 2 other assignments. Since it got broken after some AS update, I believe it was a bug (hopefully fixed) in default AS keymap for Gnome.

So I have to remove that conflict to get keys working.

Answer (score 0):

for me was needed first:

sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right  "[]"

Answer (score 0):

For me, this worked in Intellij IDE ( ubuntu )

```
File -> Settings -> Keymap --> change GNOME to Windows
```

After this change, I am able to navigate with `ALT` and `left/right` key