# Ubuntu 18.04 conflict with Intellij back/forward navigation

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, ubuntu-18.04

Intellij Navigate Back Forward conflicts in the last ubuntu version 18.04. The problem is that when I wan't to assign a new value to Navigate to workspace Left or right, I don't find them in shortcut panel.

Any solution to this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ Idea Ctrl+Alt+Left shortcut doesn't work in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808160/intellij-idea-ctrlaltleft-shortcut-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I share with you the solution I found. In a new terminal do :

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I find that newer IDEA on Ubuntu 18.04 using 'Default for GNOME' as default key map settings, which means shift + alt + left / right arrow are default values instead of previous ctrl + alt + left / right arrow.

Comment: Unfortunately this works only for editors without "sub tabs" on the bottom. If I'm editing a resource bundle for example, shift + alt + left does not take me to the previously edited file, but from the "Text" tab to the "Resource Bundle" tab within the resource editor.

Comment: I found that that's because the key binding Alt+Shift+Right/Left is also used for _Others/Select Next Tab in multi-editor file_ and _Others/Select Previous Tab in multi-editor file_ respectively. After I removed those bindings and restarted IntelliJ, i had the desired behavior.