# Running IntelliJ in WSL2 - how to make keyboard shortcut ctrl+alt+arrows work

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnome, wsl-2

My environment:

```
Windows 11 22000.493 -> Host OS
WSL 5.10.60.1
Ubuntu: 20.04.3 LTS -> Guest OS
IntelliJ: Build #IC-213.6777.52, built on January 28, 2022 -> Running inside WSL
```

I am running IntelliJ inside WSL as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

I have configured my IntelliJ to use Windows Proper Redo keymap so that my shortcuts are the same as in the Windows environment.
All shortcuts seem to work as expected except the Navigation ones - Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right.
[image]

As shown in the screenshot - they are properly configured. If I switch the combination - they start to work, but I want to have them under Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right.

I read here [IntelliJ Idea Ctrl+Alt+Left shortcut doesn't work in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808160/intellij-idea-ctrlaltleft-shortcut-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu) that Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right is interfering with Gnome but this is WSL and I have uninstalled Gnome completely by following https://askubuntu.com/questions/767577/how-can-i-remove-gnome-desktop-environment-without-messing-unity-de-ubuntu-16 and running

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Still there appear to be some settings left on my Ubuntu:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings | sort | grep Control
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels ['<Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Escape']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down ['<Super><Shift>Page_Down', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Super><Shift>Page_Up', '<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels ['<Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-panels-backward ['<Shift><Control><Alt>Tab']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down ['<Super>Page_Down', '<Control><Alt>Down']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Super>Page_Up', '<Control><Alt>Up']
```

But none of them are bound to Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right.
I am out of ideas. How do I make the keyboard combination work in IntelliJ running inside WSL2?

Comment: Do other shortcuts with Ctrl+Alt (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+S for Settings) work there? What's your keyboard layout? Do you press left or right Alt (if you have one)?

Comment: Other shortcuts with Ctrl + Alt work as expected (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+S for Settings). I tried both left and right Ctrl + Alt combinations - none work with arrows.
I temporarily switched to Alt + Shift + Arrow for Navigate Back/Forward until I find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You need to run WSL version >=56.1 as this version uses Microsoft Remote Desktop Client version 1.2.2924, which supports Ctrl+Alt+arrow key keyboard shortcuts.

https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/releases/tag/0.56.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop-whatsnew#updates-for-version-122924

Answer (score -1):

I don't known why. But if you reset this shutcut to other key. It'll work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).